# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException)

Tags: boto3, amazon-iam, aws-batch

I am having trouble submitting a AWS batch job from within another batch job:

I'm using a compute environment with the default service AWSBatchServiceRole and the default instance ecsInstanceRole. I've set up a job definition `myjobdef` with a job role `MyJobRole` that contains action * on AWS batch, just for testing. It also has a trust relationship:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
]
}
```

I'm using python 3.7 and the latest boto3. When calling `batch_client.submit_job(...)` from my local docker container with my own credentials, it works. When running the same from within a AWS batch with the mentioned roles, I get an exception:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException)
when calling the SubmitJob operation: User: arn:aws:sts::<account_id>:assumed-role/MyJobRole/xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xx is not authorized to perform: batch:SubmitJob on resource: arn:aws:batch:<region>:<account_id>:job-definition/my_job_def
```

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Your error message indicates that `batch:SubmitJob` is missing from your role. Have you added it to your batch job role?

Comment: strange - I did. But now I see everything EXCEPT submitJob is allowed and that specific action is missing from the policy! I think that what happened was that I initially added only submitJob. When it didn't work, I changed the policy to "all" via the policy editor, and it somehow inverted my selection. Thanks.

Comment: No, problem. Does it work now?

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind, I will make an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments. The issue was correctly determined to be caused by **missing permissions** to execute `batch:SubmitJob` action in the batch job role. The [action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_SubmitJob.html):

> Submits an AWS Batch job from a job definition.